# How to display 'fit' image in CSS or HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have a circular thing going on for my website ([amitnkalra.github.io](http://amitnkalra.github.io))

My image seems to be to big for this? How do I make this smaller and still show the same part of the image that it's showing right now.

I have the following code :

```
.profile {
border-radius: 150px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
        -moz-border-radius: 150px;
        background: url(img/Avatar.jpg) no-repeat;
width: 200px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #7992ce;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px #7992ce;
margin: auto;
height: 200px;
}
```

Also, my social media icons aren't displaying, they're clickable, but the icons don't show-up, why is that?

Here's the code for that:

```
.Twitter {

width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: url(img/Twitter.png);
    margin: auto;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I think that all the images you mentioned in your post should be `<img>` tags, not background images. They are part of the content. Also, your code is full of syntax errors: Your start tags all need `>` after the attributes.

Comment: What do you mean "seems to be too big for this"?

Comment: The image is too large to fit when scaled down. It has been solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divs are way smaller (25x25) than your background images, so you're only seeing fractions of them. In order to fit them you can use:

```
    background-size: 100%;
```

on all the elements that have social images set as backgrounds.

Ideally, in order to optimize the website performance and safe some bandwidth, you'd shrink those images down to 25x25 pixels (unless you use the big versions elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    text-align:center;
}

.profilePicture {
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background-image: url(http://amitnkalra.github.io/img/anotherAvatar.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 45px top;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #7992ce;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #7992ce;
    margin: auto;
}

.Twitter {
    display: inline-block;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 margin: auto;
}

.Twitter img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profilePicture"></div>

<a href="http://twitter.com/AMITNKALRA"><div class="Twitter"><img src="http://amitnkalra.github.io/img/Twitter.png" /></div></a>
```

The body css is not neccessary. I added it just to center the .Twitter
I used background-size: cover to ensure both width and height of the image fits the div and move the image to the left a bit by using background-position.